# What apparatus do physicists use to hold a photon and for how long?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics

While reading about one of the Chinese experiments I see that they propose to hold one half of a pair of entangled photons(meaning holding one photon for an amount of time) until they manage to send it from a satelite to a ground station.

Because I'm not a physicist I'm curious as to what kind of apparatus they would use for such a task and what is the maximum amount of time that a photon can be kept in the apparatus?

I'm talking about this [article](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/06/china-s-quantum-satellite-achieves-spooky-action-record-distance):

> Then he wants to demonstrate intercontinental quantum key distribution between stations in China and Austria, which will require **holding** one half of an entangled photon pair on board until the Austrian ground station appears within view of the satellite.

Comment: I guess we could try a mirrored box but is it even the same photon then?

Comment: or a long optical fibre loop...

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/498351/how-do-you-store-a-photon

Comment: usually less then a second is how long they can hold it between mirrors

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is EIT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_transparency)

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei: thanks for the link, I imaged it has something to do with mirrors but I was not sure.

Comment: @flippiefanus: can EIT work with entangled photons?

Comment: As far as I know yes, because they want to use it for quantum repeaters with quantum teleport

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: my only concern with the solution there is how much time the photon is "held". The experiment in my question I think requires holding a photon for a longer period of time(until the satellite passes over and can send the photon to the second station on the ground).

Comment: @CristiB Indeed, what you want to do in such a case is to transfer the information to a different carrier (say, an atom in a cavity), and then convert it again into a photon later.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: can you please write that in the form of an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate because the question text, in its current form, is a duplicate of the thread mentioned above. If you want a more specific answer, then please edit your question to be clear about what you're asking and how it differs from the previous threads.